# How could a t-test be used for comparing two ML algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, t-test, algorithms, method-comparison

I am new to ML, and I am reading a paper about ML comparison. It underlines the comparison between two algorithms based on the t-test but it does not describe the process further.

I know what a t-test is, but I don't understand how to implement it for ML algorithm comparison.

Comment: If you would like a relevant explanation, you will need to tell us more about how this t-test is applied. At least please provide a link to the paper if you can.

Comment: Welcome Erogoi.  We are the CV community.  I have never heard of the ML community.  You need to give us more specifics.  Is the likelihood function for n independent and identically distributed normal random variables with both mean and variance unknown?  I would expect so since the t test is mentioned. The t test is a hypothesis test and the MLE is a method for obtaining point estimates. So what sort of connection between the two are they talking about.

Comment: If it is to relate the t statistic to the MLEs for the mean and variance under these normality assumptions that I asked about, then I can answer your question.

Comment: Are you asking in terms of comparing model performance (e.g. comparing the accuracy of two classifiers with cross validation)? Something along these lines: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf OR Tom Mitchell: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fcs.cmu.edu%2Fproject%2Ftheo-20%2Fwww%2Fmlbook%2Fch5.pdf&ei=IBVeULf-OaWMygHh94CACw&usg=AFQjCNHWtM6qALWSLfijfMwKakNWGFwTSA

Comment: @Erogol I accepted jonsca's edit of your post because I think it makes the intent of the question clear.  But there is a possibility that it changes your meaning.  Let us know if it does and we will make any necessary corrections.

Comment: @Erogol A link to the paper you're reading could be helpful in getting the context to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $t$ statistic is a sample mean divided by a sample estimate of the standard error.  The sample mean is the mle for the mean of the normal distribution.  The mle for the variance of the normal is

$S^2 =\Sigma(X_i-X_b)^2/n$ where $X_b$ is the sample mean which is the mle for the mean.  The standard error in the denominator of the $t$ statistic is $S\sqrt{1/(n-1)}$.

Comment: This sounds confused to me. The t test has nothing to do with MLE and the standard error *by definition* is $1/\sqrt{n}$ times the estimate of $S$, not $1/\sqrt{n-1}$ times it. Indeed, maximum likelihood tests differ from the standard t test because the MLE of $S$ is not the unbiased estimator used in the t test.  I am also mystified by the emphasis on maximum likelihood in this answer: I suspect the question may have to do with *Machine Learning* rather than *maximum likelihood*!

Comment: @whuber No one said that there was any important relationship but the OP seemed to ask for any connection between the mle and the t test.  I am not sure that the edited title is really what the OP intended.  That is why I made the comment to the OP.  I was trying to show how the t statistic relates to the maximum likelihood estimates for the mean and variance of a normal random sample. The sample mean is the mle for the population mean of course and the mle for variance is V=∑(X$_i$-X$_b$)$^2$/n.

Comment: The standard error is S=√{∑(Xi-Xb)2/[n(n-1)]}=√V [√1/(n-1)], right?

Comment: Yes, it is, but not for the reasons you supplied.

Comment: @whuber What do you mean? Isn't that exactly what I used in the formula for the t statistic?

Comment: In your answer, you began with the MLE of $S$ and then divided it by $\sqrt{n-1}$, rather than beginning with a *different* (non-MLE) estimator (based on the unbiased estimate of the variance) and dividing it by $\sqrt{n}$. I would be interested in seeing how the MLE theory justifies your approach--because I think it does not. I believe it ought to lead you to a slightly different test (one that is inferior to the t-test for small samples).

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my point.  I took the mle only to show how the usual t statistic could be formed from it.  All I did (I think) was a little algebra to convert the mle estimate of variance to the unbiased estimate of variance and then take the square root to form the appropriate denominator for the statndard t test.  I was not trying to change the test.  I was just trying to express the test statistic algebraically in terms of the mles for the mean and standard deviation which should be easy to do and changes nothing.